# Linux Shared Libraries c++

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, shared-libraries

I have a Shared Library wise.so. How I can use it in my programm? Do I need to include headers of that library?

I work with Eclipce under Linux. I have set a path to the library using -L and -l. But my function is not visible in the program.

Could you explain me how does Shared Library work?

Regards.

EDIT:

I get the following error:

```
int main() {
    char* path = "/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/proj1/src/pic.jpg";
    CEDD_Descriptor::CEDD ced; // undefined reference to `CEDD_Descriptor::CEDD::CEDD[in-charge]()'
    ced.execute(path);
}
```

Header:

```
class CEDD
    {
        public:
            CEDD(double Th0, double Th1, double Th2, double Th3,bool CompactDescriptor);
            CEDD();
            ~CEDD(void);

            double T0;
            double T1;
            double T2;
            double T3;
            bool Compact;

            double* execute(char* path);

        private:
            int cedd_segnum;                //number of segments
            int* cedd_partitionSize;        //number of pixels in each segment
    };
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to include the header file in your application and link against it.

Have a look at how to use libraries in [shared libraries](http://www.linux.org/docs/ldp/howto/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) and [Linux howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/).

If the header file is not in the same directory as your application (which it usually isn't) then you need to tell compiler where to look for it, you use `-I/path/to/include` to include path to include directory that contains the header file.

In linking step you need to point to the library. The general usage is to use `-L/path/to/lib` is path to directory containing your library followed by `-l<libname>` where `<libname>` is the name of library without `lib` e.g. if you have `libboost_serialization-d-1_34_1.so` you would use `-lboost_serialization-d-1_34_1`

Examples:

```
g++ -I/sw/include -Wall -g -I/usr/local/include/boost-1_36/ -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -L/sw/lib -lboost_serialization-d-1_34_1 -o x main.o
```

Comment: "undefined reference to `CEDD_Descriptor::CEDD::CEDD[in-charge]()" sounds like linker can't find symbols in library, do you use -L/library/path/to/lib -llibname to link?

Answer (score 0):

Have you also modified the Include path (the -I option) so it knows where to look for the headers for the library?  If you haven't done this then the compiler will complain about being unable to find functions/classes/structures/etc.